# composition of p-adic power series

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Take $K$ to be a finite (complete) extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Consider two power series $f(x), g(x) \in K[[x]]$ such that $g(0)$ has positive valuation. For this question let's assume $h(x) = f(g(x))$ is defined as a formal power series, and has some radius of convergence.

Now suppose the radius of convergence of $f$ is $r_2 > 0$ and the radius of convergence of $g$ is $r_1>0$. Suppose also $x_0$ is a point such that $g(x_0)$ converges and $|g(x_0)| < r_2$. Does this imply $h(x_0)$ must also converge, or do there exists examples of series $f,g$ satisfying the above where $h(x_0)$ does not converge?

Just for some context if I understand correctly we may sometimes have the function $h$ is defined at a point $x_0$, yet it is not equal to $f$ applied to $g(x_0)$. I am just trying to get a better idea of how poorly behaved composition of p-adic power series might be.

Edit: thanks to reuns comment I see we need $f$ to converge on some neighborhood of $g(x_0)$. If we assume this condition is true is it enough to get that $h(x_0)$ converges?

Edit 2: maybe it is better to ask if this question is true when $g(0) = 0$, and the composition of formal power series is actually defined. So let's ask the same question now assuming $g(0) =0$.

Comment: No problem for the convergence of $h(x_0)$ because $v(g_n(x_0))< r_2$ for $n$ large enough, where $g_n$ is the sequence of polynomial truncations of $g$. So we are in the domain of convergence and uniform continuity of $f$ (this is the key point, that $f(a)$ converges with $a=g(x_0)$ is not enough, we need that $f$ converges in some neighborhood of $a$)

Comment: Thank you for your comment reuns, but I think I am missing something. Let's suppose we are in the case $g(0) = 0$. Could you please explain how we go from $g_n(x_0)$ being in the domain of convergence of $f$ to getting $h$ converges at $x_0$?